# Adding marker lines on ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How can I add a line onto each bar in a ggplot barplot?

For example, using the built-in ggplot example:

```
mm <- ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarise, mmpg = mean(mpg))
ggplot(mm, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mmpg)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

produces this

[image]

Now I have a vector `y <- c(10, 5, 5)`, which is the height at which I want to plot a line on each bar, producing something like this

[image]

How can I do it? I tried `geom_hline`, but that produces lines that cut across the entire chart instead.

Comment: Can you post your exact code that generates the second plot? 

I'm not certain there is a straightforward solution to your question, but perhaps we can work something out. In the meantime (and you've probably already consulted this), <http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_hline.html> might help.

Comment: The "code" for second plot was Paint in Windows to add 3 white lines on the .PNG exported of the first plot :)

Comment: Oh cool. I was excited because I'd never seen anything that does that out of ggplot2 :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
y <- c(10, 5, 5)

mm <- ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarise, mmpg = mean(mpg))
mm <- cbind(mm, y) # get vector into data frame

ggplot(mm, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mmpg)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
geom_errorbar(aes(yintercept = y, ymax=y, ymin=y), 
              color = "white", size = 2)
```

We use `geom_errorbar()`to draw the lines in the data frame and then reduce their width by manually setting `ymax` and `ymin` to the `y`value.

The above code produces this result:

[image]

Credit goes to [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Lines_(ggplot2)/) source.